# Flot chart displaying data from data that aren't even in JSON

Tags: javascript, flot

I have the following

```
<div id="chart"></div>

<script src="js/flot/jquery.flot.js"></script>
<script src="js/flot/jquery.flot.tooltip.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/flot/jquery.flot.resize.js"></script>

var sessions = [
[1418706000000, 14813],
[1418792400000, 39580],
[1418878800000, 51193],
[1418965200000, 66700],
[1419051600000, 108737],
[1419138000000, 101081],
[1419224400000, 94449],
[1419310800000, 109039],
[1419397200000, 92329],
[1419483600000, 68942],
[1419570000000, 75391],
[1419656400000, 120016],
[1419742800000, 132495],
[1419829200000, 103469],
[1419915600000, 88940],
[1420002000000, 59938],
[1420088400000, 72359],
[1420174800000, 74663]
];

var users = [
[1418706000000, 2632],
[1418792400000, 9588],
[1418878800000, 9273],
[1418965200000, 10839],
[1419051600000, 14948],
[1419138000000, 11226],
[1419224400000, 13394],
[1419310800000, 10493],
[1419397200000, 8482],
[1419483600000, 2375],
[1419570000000, 5783],
[1419656400000, 10068],
[1419742800000, 8288],
[1419829200000, 5423],
[1419915600000, 4866],
[1420002000000, 1862],
[1420088400000, 5560],
[1420174800000, 1257]
];

function doPlot(position) {
    $.plot($("#chart"), [{
        data: sessions,
        label: "Sessions"
    }, {
        data: revenue,
        label: "Revenue",
        yaxis: 2
    }], {
        xaxes: [{
            mode: 'time'
        }],
        yaxes: [{
            min: 0
        }, {
            alignTicksWithAxis: position == "right" ? 1 : null,
            position: position
        }],
        legend: {
            position: 'sw'
        },
        grid: {
            hoverable: true 
        },
        tooltip: true,
        tooltipOpts: {
           content: "%s for %x was %y",
           xDateFormat: "%y-%0m-%0d",
           onHover: function (flotItem, $tooltipEl) {

           }
        }
     });
  }

  doPlot("right");
```

Thhis displays figures for both sessions and users on dates that there isn't even data for. The last date that there is data for is Dec 27th. Yet, this line graph shows data for up until Jan 2nd.

Here is a working example [here](http://lancenewman.me/marketing/link.php)

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your last data entry in each array element time = 1420174800000, so:

```
var date = new Date(1420174800000);

// output "Fri, 02 Jan 2015 05:00:00 GMT"
console.log(date.toGMTString());
```

Comment: Ahhh. I see. I was using `(strtotime($date[$i])*100)` to get that timestamp. Where the $date variables in the arrays are in the `date('D, M j')` format. Do you know how to correctly get the timestamp to plugin the JSON?

Comment: If you use php `strtotime` it returs timestamp in seconds, but javascript `Date` expects timestamp in millisecond, in that case you should multiply by 1000 `(strtotime($date[$i])*1000)`. Also check for php `$date` array contents `var_dump($date)`

Answer (score 1):

I converted your data to dates:

```
date = new Date(sessions[i][0])
```

It contains dates between **Dec 16 2014** and **Jan 02 2015**. You can see it in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3YQq2/1/).
When you fill your arrays, you should convert your dates to numbers simply with:

```
sessions[i] = [Number(date), value];
```

I'm not sure how you meant `Date('D, M j')`, I assume it's a string like `"Date(month,day,year)"`. An example of converting this kinf of json to plottable data: [in this other fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3YQq2/2/).

Actually, I reversed the day and month, but you get the idea. :)

Comment: Ahhh. I see. I was using (strtotime($date[$i])*100) to get that timestamp. Where the $date variables in the arrays are in the date('D, M j') format. Do you know how to correctly get the timestamp to plugin the JSON?